# Django: Выполнение задачи Celery при сохранении формы

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery

Есть форма по модели для отправки файла. Надо сделать так, чтобы при сохранении формы выполнялся таск celery именно для этого файла.
С Celery работаю только второй день.

models.py

```py
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default='False')
```

views.py

```py
def home(request):
    files = UploadFile.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload_file_form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if upload_file_form.is_valid():
            upload_file_form.save()
            return redirect(home)
    else:
        upload_file_form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'testfileapp/home.html', {
        'files': files,
        'upload_file_form': upload_file_form,
    })
```

сам таск должен подождать некоторое время после загрузки файла и передать статус этого файла.
Огромная просьба подробнее ответить на вопрос, так как инфы по нему маловато, а то, что есть не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться сигналом `post_save` для этой задачи.

Сам сигнал срабатывает (то есть, выполняется функция `notify`) после сохранения модели. В функцию передаются несколько аргументов, один из которых — `created`, означающий, была ли запись создана только что.

Для того чтобы запускать задачу на конкретный экземпляр, передайте `pk` (уникальный ключ), а в самой задаче получите по нему запись. И вообще, большинство логики старайтесь реализовывать в задачах `Celery` (например, задержку перед отправкой), потому что они выполняются асинхронно.

***Пример (`signals.py`):***

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import UploadFile
from .tasks import some_task


@receiver(post_save, sender=UploadFile)
def notify(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        some_task.delay(instance.pk)
```

Comment: а как сама задача выглядеть будет, просто передаем pk и время задержки?
не могу понять саму структуру, откуда куда и что

Comment: @Alex Вы примете в задаче ("таске" `Celery`) `pk`, по этому `pk` получите запись, которая только что была создана, например, так: `UploadFile.objects.get(pk=pk)`, а дальше делайте с ней, всё, что пожелаете :) Нужно подождать — ждите (`sleep`, хотя лучше ждать до получения записи). А сервер в это время продолжит принимать запросы.

Comment: подскажите как передать этот pk. Из представления?, если да, то как, DetailView page у меня нету, все на главной странице. Насколько я знаю, чтобы передать этот pk в представлении,нужно указывать обязательный параметр функции рядом с request.
А в сам таск модель не импортируется, ошибку выдает

Comment: сам таск примерно такой
`from celery import shared_task`
`from .models import UploadFile`

`@shared_task`
`def set_status_as_inactive(pk):`
   ` UploadFile.objects.get(pk=pk)`
и тут выдает ошибку `ImportError: cannot import name 'UploadFile`

Comment: @Alex Нет, представление Вы вообще не меняете. Я в примере уже передаю `pk`. Просто в задаче примите его. Получаю я его из записи, которая передаётся в функцию-обработчик сигнала.

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупые вопросы, но как его принять?) Первый раз со всем этим сталкиваюсь

Comment: @Alex Параметром в Вашей задаче: `def some_task(pk)`. У Вас ошибка `ImportError`, потому что Вы модель не импортировали. Я не знаю, где она у Вас, но попробуйте: `from .models import UploadFile`.

Comment: так я так и передаю этот аргумент, и импортирую модель в tasks.py `from .models import UploadFile`, но ошибка остается

Comment: @Alex Я не знаю структуру Вашего проекта, поэтому не могу сказать, откуда Вам следует импортировать модель :( Если совсем ничего не получится, добавьте её (структуру папок) в вопрос.

Comment: ну файл с тасками находится в самом приложении где models, views, signals и т.д. Оно как бы импортируется, но при запуске сервера выдает ошибку.
Может у Вас есть менторство, был бы очень благодарен, если б помогли разобраться с этим)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102464/discussion-between-nomnoms12-and-alex).